# Spring Cloud Dataflow Kubernetes get properties of jar from dockerfile

Tags: java, spring, docker, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow

How can i read the properties of the JAR i have created as a task when I import it as a task app in the spring cloud dataflow kubernetes server via docker image url?

Answer (score 2):

You'll notice the following in the [Installation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes/docs/1.7.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#kubernetes-getting-started) section of the reference guide.

> Currently, only applications registered with a --uri property pointing to a Docker resource are supported by the Data Flow Server for Kubernetes. However, we do support Maven resources for the --metadata-uri property, which is used to list the properties supported by each application.

Once when you have a [dedicated companion artifact](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.7.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-stream-app-metadata-artifact) (see: [maven plugin](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-app-starters-maven-plugins/tree/master/spring-cloud-app-starter-metadata-maven-plugin)), you'd be able to register the docker artifact along with the companion artifact via `--uri` and `--metadata-uri` properties respectively.

There is no other solution to resolve properties directly from the Docker images. We have tried different approaches in the past, but nothing worked out. If you have ideas, feel free to open a pull request, we can take it from there.